# Start other application on my application same windows

Tags: android, android-layout

On my device running Android 6.0, there is manufacturer application video (AppA). I want to develop my own application (AppB) which screen is divided into 2 layouts, the first layout shows buttons (Activity AppB) and the second layout show Manufacturer application (Activity AppA).

Is it possible to do that? Can you explain how please?

Thank you.

Comment: There is no support in Android for embedding the activities of one app in another app, sorry.

Comment: Note that Android does not support the concept of "windows" like a desktop computer does.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your question well, this [article](https://www.xda-developers.com/android-q-splitscreen-multitasking-multi-resume/) might help you. 
Though not using your phone (Android 6) and no app would run inside another app.
Long story short: The functionality (called multi-resume) of running 2 apps side-by-side in split screen mode would be added with Android Q (as per the article).
You could then exploit this feature and implement interactions between appA & appB through intents.